# App Store Review Multiple In-app Purchase Methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase

We're having some trouble with the App Store Review Guidelines, specifically these two points in section 11 - Purchasing and currencies:

> 11.1
>
> Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected
>
> 11.2
>
> Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an app will be rejected

We're making an app for iOS, Android and Blackberry. We wish to provide in-app purchases for iOS and SMS for all three alongside. We can't quite depict from the guidelines whether we can have text underneath an in-app purchase button saying "or SMS XXX to XXXXX" and have them enter the password received back to their phone.

Yes we're using another system to the IAP, but we're offering that at the same time. Could SMS be counted as a different "mechanism"?

Any help on this would be much appreciated. I don't fancy the idea of submitting our app for approval after setting this all up just to have it rejected and have things delayed for weeks.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Seeing that Apple forced Amazon.com, Kodo and others all to remove any link, mention etc of their stores, I'd say the chances are high you'll get rejected.

Comment: I'd be curious if anyone could comment on 11.1 in terms of unlocking content for promotional uses.  I would like to enable free unlocking for certain users (who might submit their email address for a one-time unlock).  But 11.1 seems to nix that idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending an unlock code via SMS will almost certainly be considered a "mechanism other than the App Store" (11.1), and be used as a cause for rejection.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that. Apple will reject your app. They don't want any other IAP methods, because they won't earn any money from it! StoreKit is just the easiest and best (and the only :P) API for IAP. Either you just use regular IAP or you will have to stick with Cydia. You can make your app free in Cydia and then manage your own IAP using SMS or how ever you want it to be.